# abbreviated database records but problem arised while word search

Tags: php, laravel, search

I have a website under construction that has database column 'gender' and 'size' in a table in mysql. they are enumeration with m,f,both for gender and s,m,l,xl for size. When showing these datas in blades, i have used arrays for proper views.

Now i am implementing a search feature and its working ok. When i type 'm' as keywords, all filters work and search results are shown but problem arises when i type 'male', as no results are shown.

```
public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value, $checkbox)
{
    //i am using a temporary fix like this. I need a proper fix for this.
    if(strtolower($value) == "male"){ 
        $value = "m";
    } else if (strtolower($value) == "female") {
        $value = "f";
    } else if (strtolower($value) == "other") {
        $value = "both";
    }
    if($checkbox == null) {
        $a = $builder->whereHas ('product', function ($a) use ($value) {
            $a->where('gender', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
        });
    } else {
        $a = $builder->whereHas ('product', function ($a) use ($value) {
            $a->where('gender', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
        })->whereRaw('`stocks`.`quantity` < `stocks`.`low_stock_threshold`');
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code to be able to understand the problem better. eg is it a PHP problem or a SQL problem or a Laravel problem?

Comment: Exactly, @Shiraj you must show us some code to help us understand your problem.

Comment: It is obvious that 'male' is not the same as enumeration of 'm' thats why the search does not match.

Comment: sorry for that. but ive added some codes of my search filter for column 'gender' in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can fix the solution at your sql script level, below is my suggestion.

You can first normalize your search text to match your abbreviated text and then apply that normalized text in your where condition.

Below is one of the way you could do that,

```
DECLARE @GenderSearchText NVARCHAR(50) = 'female'
DECLARE @NormalizedSearchText NVARCHAR(50)

SET @NormalizedSearchText = 
CASE 
    WHEN @GenderSearchText = 'M' OR @GenderSearchText = 'Male'
        THEN 'M'
    WHEN @GenderSearchText = 'F' OR @GenderSearchText = 'Female'
        THEN 'F'
    ELSE    @GenderSearchText
END

SELECT @NormalizedSearchText 

--<<APPLY THIS @NormalizedSearchText to your actual where condition>>
```

Comment: Is this somewhat similar to what i have done in my "later added coding part" in my question?

Comment: Ya, I just saw your code, it is something similar, but done at sql script level

Answer (score 0):

In your config file define an array of these abbreviations as keys for the array like this:

> $array{
>       'm'=>'male' }

Now for $value in your search query use this array - $array[$value]. In your case it will look like:

> $a->where('gender', 'LIKE', '%' . $array[$value]. '%');